# как изменить один элемента кортежа в листе?

Tags: c#, .net

у меня такой вопрос: создал лист кортежа, который принимает 2 параметра, DateTIme и string , теперь питаюсь в этих кортежах изменить DateTime, ну типа сортировать, НО сортировать HE целиком кортежи, а конкретно один item1 кортежа а конкретнее DateTime, вот:
так -->
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
public static void Main()
{

```
  List<(DateTime, string)> list = new List<(DateTime, string)>();
    list.Add((DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), "test"));
    list.Add((DateTime.Now.AddDays(3), "test2"));
    list.Add((DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), "test3"));
    
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            DateTime temp=list[j].Item1;
            list[j].Item1 = list[j+1].Item1;
            list[j].Item1 = temp;
            
        }
    }
}
```

по моему я нашел решение:

```
   for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (list[j].Item1> list[j+1].Item1 )
            {
                (DateTime, string) turple;
                turple.Item1 = list[j].Item1.AddDays(1);
                turple.Item2 = list[j].Item2;

                list[j] = turple;
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: ну я догадываюсь что тут причина в том как передаются реферальные типи, но до конца не понимаю как это делать , с листом не так давно работаю...

Comment: Что делает этот код? Зачем вам здесь вообще котрежи? Какую именно задачу решаете?

Comment: ну изначально я хотел в лист кортежей передать из ВИнФормса данные Дату и название сотрудника, так хотел собрать данные о всех сотрудниках, потом их сортировать распределить чтобы  были 2 сотрудника с одинаковыми датами, что та типа, программа которая высчитывает график рабочих которые работают по сменна.... но потом это решил сделать чуть по другому, а этот вопрос с изменением итема кортежа  остался открытым, вот решил за одно и с этим разобраться....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тапл - структура, при обращении к списку по индексу вы получаете ее копию, и изменение не имеет никакого смысла. Об этом компилятор вас любезно и предупреждает.

Пузырька же делаете? Надо же целиком элементы махнуть, верно? Давайте с теми же кортежами:

```
if (list[j].Item1 > list[j + 1].Item1)
{
    (list[j], list[j + 1]) = (list[j + 1], list[j]);
}
```

Comment: н а разве тут у вас не получился кортеж который в свою очередь состоит из двух кортежей?

Comment: по моему я нашел решение:

Comment: @GiorgiTamazashvili вы бы сначала попробовали, конструкция `(x, y) = (y, x)` просто меняет значения местами. Это свойство кортежа и к типу данных в самом списке не имеет никакого отношения. Конструкция-деконструкция.

Comment: ой... извините я немножко новичок :)) об этом не знал.... :)) спасибо попробую :)